# Need to pass textbox value to ajax call when a radio btn is clicked--Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<input tabindex="4" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm"  name="pincode_id" value="'.$rpin.'" id="pincode_id" placeholder="Pincode">
<input tabindex="4" value="0"  type="radio" placeholder="COD" onclick="token()" name="pay_type" id="pay_type_cod">COD
```

//Ajax call

```
 function token(){
 $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      url: "./ajax/token.php", 
      data: { "sub_sessionid": $("#sub_sessionid").val(),"pincode_id":$("#pincode_id").val()},
      success: function(data) { 
 // alert("hitest");
        if(data==1){
            $("#msg").html("COD Not Applicable");
            $("#pay_type_prepaid").prop("checked",true);
        }
      } 
 });


}
```

I need to send `pin_code_id` to ajax call token() when i click on Radio btn COD...Please can any one help

Comment: what error you are geting?

Comment: yeah thanks for helping but there is issue with my firebug so initially  it dint showed me pincode but after restarting firefox it worked tanq @suren srapyan